# selected item should not appear in spinner again for selection

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-custom-view

i have a spinner with these items

```
<string-array name="spnr_browse_array">
        <item>Browse By</item>
        <item>Category</item>
        <item>Subject</item>
        <item>Author</item>
    </string-array>
```

when i click the spinner it shows the drop down list as usually as shown in picture.
[image]

Now i actually want is that the item "Browse By" should not appear in the drop-down again when it is selected, it should be look like this..

[image]

so how can i achieve this
is this possible in spinner or not.
Please tell other alternative for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
android:prompt="Browse By"
```

in your xml file for the spinner. It will appear as heading for those list of items.

Comment: thanx for answering dear chaitanya.but the question is not,how to give heading or hint to spinner.The question is how to hide the selected item from spinner items when the particuler item is selected.and when selection changes how to make it visible again in spinner items.

Comment: @hamad Okay! I din't get that properly. I think for this, within the `OnItemSelected` of spinner you will be getting the view of the item selected. You can make it invisible, this should work fine. Please try out this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the text `Browse By` as the title of your spinner in your layout as below by setting its property `android:prompt` .

> ```
>   <Spinner
>       android:id="@+id/spinner"
>       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>       android:prompt="Browse By" <---- Check here.
>       />
> ```

Comment: grishu thanks for reply...but it is not the thing i want,browseby is also an item of spinner,i want to show it in list also,but not at that time..when it is selected already.when selection changes it should go back in spinner list.

Comment: That you have to manage manually by urself for each selected items to show and hide.